# how to access a non static member from a static method in java?

Tags: java, static

I have a situation where i have to access a non static member from inside a static method. I can access it with new instance, but current state will be lost as non static member will be re-initialized. How to achieve this without losing data?

Comment: That makes no sense. Inside the static function, there is no such thing as "the current state", since there's no instance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why would you have to that?

Comment: Provide some code of what you're trying to do, as well as a description of the actual problem (in terms of your functional requirements, not technical constraints).

Comment: Down-vote will be changed to an up-vote once the original poster clarifies their original post as has been repeatedly requested. At present it's unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want a [singleton](http://www.theserverside.de/singleton-pattern-in-java/). Then you could get the (only) instance of the class from within a static method and access its members.

The basic idea is

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton instance = null;

  private Singleton() {}

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

and then in some static method:

```
public static someMethod() {
    Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
    //do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for doesn't really make sense. Just make your method non-static because your static method cannot be tied to an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods do not apply to a particular instance/object, they're a class-level thing. Because of that, they're not *given* an instance reference. So, no you cannot do this.

If you can work out *which* instance reference to use another way, you could access the non-static methods of it.

Or, alternatively, re-architect your classes so that it's a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A static method is not associated with any particular state (aka any non-static members). In other words, they operate independently of any particular instance of the class so they cannot depend on non-static members.

Answer (score 0):

A non static member variable "is state". It's the state **of a** specific instance of that class.

When you say you want to access a non-static member variable, it's as good as saying "want to access a non-static member variable **of a specific instance of class XXX**", I mean the bolded part is implicit.

So it doesn't make sense to say "I can access it with new instance".